# Content & Google Map full height and width of each column in Bootstrap 2-column layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and have a webpage with a fixed header, fixed footer and 2 responsive columns (sm-4 and sm-8).

What I'd like to do is:

- have both columns fill the rest of the height between the header and
  footer
- have the right-hand column filled with a google map
- the text div to position itself above the map div when collapsed to a smaller screen

I've managed to load in the map however cannot get it to display full height and width of the 1 column only. If I try to set width: 100% then it jumps to full width of the screen rather than the column. I've also tried setting the left div to right 30% left 0 and the right div to left 70% and right 0 but this affects the responsiveness on a mobile device. I found lots of other posts but they all mess with the responsiveness that I'm trying to achieve.

This is what I want to achieve on a larger screen:

[image]

And on a smaller screen I'd like two divs to stack on top of each other in between the header and footer.

This is my container for both columns:

```
<div class="container">   
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4" id="testing_employers">
       texttexttexttexttexttexttext
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-8" id="map">
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My full code (back to the most recent "working" version) is on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/havm4197/

Comment: Could you fix the map in the example? It will be easier to help you with.

Comment: I don't work with bootstrap, so I won't answer to your question, but you should be careful with smaller screen.
If your smaller screen is a touchscreen device and your map cover the entire screen, the user may not be able to scroll your website. I'm not sure how google map is dealing with touch screen device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem except on my layout I don't need the footer and I also used different column size arrangement. But I believe conceptually it is the same problem. On my case I make it work like this:

```
   <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand Title</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                <p>Side Text</p>
            </div>
            <div id="map" class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then I used this CSS:

```
#map {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.container-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Please give it a try and let me know if also worked for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

```css
#left {
  min-height: 50vh;
  width: auto;
}

#map {
  min-height: 50vh;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid m-0 p-0">
  <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-light bg-light  m-0 p-0">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sticky Header</a>
  </nav>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 m-0 p-0">
      <div id="left" style="background-color:blue;">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 m-0 p-0">
      <div id="map" style="background-color:red;">

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar sticky-bottom navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Sticky Fotter</a>
  </nav>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```